# How do I Convert a list to dataframe in for bucle

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, data-science

I appreciate your collaboration to convert the result code into a dataframe with the 2 columns. I was able to do the for loop to print each result and now I need to save this data to a dataframe. But I have not been able to get the result correct. Can you help me?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get('https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-table') #get page web information
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') # interpreter
print(soup.prettify())
print(soup.title)

league_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'standing-table__table callfn')

for team in league_table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = team.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        pl_team = row.find('td', class_ ='standing-table__cell standing-table__cell--name')
        pl_team = pl_team['data-long-name']
        points = row.find_all('td', class_ = 'standing-table__cell')[9].text
        print(pl_team, points)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas. You can do it in 1 line.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-table')[0]
```

**Ouput:**

```
print(df[['Team','Pts']])
                        Team  Pts
0            Manchester City   83
1          Manchester United   71
2                    Chelsea   67
3                  Liverpool   66
4             Leicester City   66
5            West Ham United   62
6          Tottenham Hotspur   59
7                    Everton   59
8                    Arsenal   58
9               Leeds United   56
10               Aston Villa   52
11   Wolverhampton Wanderers   45
12            Crystal Palace   44
13               Southampton   43
14          Newcastle United   42
15  Brighton and Hove Albion   41
16                   Burnley   39
17                    Fulham   28
18      West Bromwich Albion   26
19          Sheffield United   20
```